# What groupbox method (if any) monitors radio button selections?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm creating a VB.NET application that includes two radio buttons inside of a groupbox.  If the first radio button is selected, a certain tab on a tab form should be enabled.  If the second radio button is selected, that tab should be disabled.

Is there a groupbox method that monitors both radio buttons and fires when the selection changes?  Or do I need to set up individual methods for each radio button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the event to each individual radio button

[RadioButton.CheckedChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx)